# toolbar animation on extending search bar does not work swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation, swiftui-toolbar, swiftui-transition

I want to animate the extending search bar. When I press the search button, I want to extend the search bar to left, and when I close the search text field, to collapse to right.

```
           ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
                    
                    HStack{
                        
                        if self.showSearchBar{
                            HStack{
                                
                                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")

                                
                                TextField("search from menu", text: self.$txtSearch)
                                
                                Button{
                                    
                                    withAnimation{
                                        self.showSearchBar.toggle()
                                    }
                                    
                                } label:{
                                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                                }
                            }.frame(width: 300, height: 40)
                            
                            
                        }else{
                            Button{
                                                        
                                withAnimation{
                                    self.showSearchBar.toggle()
                                }
                                
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }.padding(self.showSearchBar ? 10 : 0)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    
                }
```

The video of how it is right now:
https://files.fm/f/au967z3bh

I know that is possible to extend smoothly from right to left when expanding and left to right when collapsing. How I can add that to my code?

I want similar to this: https://files.fm/u/pgxtzvrk7

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to have animation, you mustn't use `if {} else {}`. Because when the condition was changed, nothing was linked between your views, so it will render a new UI element instead of animating two views.

However, using an animation namespace might be the solution to your problem. Read more about `@Namespace` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/namespace).

Declaration:

```swift
@Namespace private var animated
```

put it into the struct which contains your views. Then add the following property:

```swift
.matchedGeometryEffect(id: "searchBar", in: animated)
```

like this:

```swift
HStack {
    if self.showSearchBar {
        HStack{
            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                // Here vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "searchBar", in: animated)
            
            TextField("Search from menu", text: .constant(""))
            
            Button {
                withAnimation{
                    self.showSearchBar.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "xmark")
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 40)
    } else {
        Button {
            withAnimation {
                self.showSearchBar.toggle()
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
        }
        // Here vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "searchBar", in: animated)
    }
}
.padding(self.showSearchBar ? 10 : 0)
.background(Color.white)
.cornerRadius(20)
```

Hope this help!

Comment: This still does not work, is it because that is in the toolbar item?

Comment: Also how i can add the effect expanding from right to left and collapsing from left to right like here: https://files.fm/u/pgxtzvrk7